# retaining column names in lapply(.SD,...) for data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

When applying a function with multiple output variables (e.g., a list) to a subset of a data.table, I lose the variable names. Is there a way to retain them?

```
library(data.table)

foo <- function(x){
  list(mn = mean(x), sd = sd(x))
}

bar <- data.table(x=1:8, y=c("d","e","f","g"))

# column names "mn" and "sd" are replaced by "V1" and "V2"
bar[, sapply(.SD, foo), by = y, .SDcols="x"]

# column names "mn" and "sd" are retained
bar_split <- split(bar$x, bar$y)
t(sapply(bar_split, foo))
```

Comment: how about `bar[,c("mn","sd"):=sapply(.SD,foo),.(y),.SDcols="x"]`

Comment: Nice question. I'd be interested in doing this for functions that return more than just a list of scalars, something like `foo2 <- function(x) list(mn=mean(x),tab=table(x))`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would go wit the following, which is a bit awkward, but doesn't require writing the names manually no matter how many functions there are

```
bar[, as.list(unlist(lapply(.SD, foo))), by = y, .SDcols = "x"]
#    y x.mn     x.sd
# 1: d    3 2.828427
# 2: e    4 2.828427
# 3: f    5 2.828427
# 4: g    6 2.828427
```

The biggest advantage of this approach is that it binds the functions with the column names. If, for example, you would have an additional column, it will still give an informative result while using the same code as above

```
set.seed(1)
bar[, z := sample(8)]
bar[, as.list(unlist(lapply(.SD, foo))), by = y, .SDcols = c("x", "z")]
#    y x.mn     x.sd z.mn      z.sd
# 1: d    3 2.828427  2.0 1.4142136
# 2: e    4 2.828427  7.5 0.7071068
# 3: f    5 2.828427  3.0 1.4142136
# 4: g    6 2.828427  5.5 0.7071068
```

Comment: Does `x` need to be quoted as `"x"`? - it does in 1.9.4 at least.

Comment: @thelatemail Good point, I'm using `1.9.5`. Fixed. BTW, in `1.9.5` you can now do stuff such as `.SDcols = x:y`, for example.

Comment: This works for most simple cases, but is it possible to use `replicate` instead of `lapply` or `sapply` without creating `n` new columns? For example, `bar[, replicate(n=3, foo(.SD$x)), .(y)]` adds a new pair of columns for each replicate and the `as.list(unlist(...))` trick doesn't seem to retain the column names.

Answer (score 3):

The setNames function lets you add back the missing character vector.:

```
bar[, setNames( sapply(.SD, foo), c("mn", "sd")), by = y, .SDcols="x"]
   y mn       sd
1: d  3 2.828427
2: e  4 2.828427
3: f  5 2.828427
4: g  6 2.828427
```

The authors suggested using the other form suggested by Arenburg:

```
DT[, c('x2', 'y2') := list(x / sum(x), y / sum(y)), by = grp]
```